# Is it ok if Helper will interact with Model?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Is it ok if Helper will interact with Model or not?

For example, I have helper generating custom `<select>` for choosing categories.
Right now I'm extracting data for this `<select>` in Controller (using Model, of couse) and then assigning it to View.

But there is another way to do. Just put interaction with Model into Helper. It will make Controller's code more simple and will help us avoid duplicating code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've seen, accessing model data from wherever is considered fine, but modifying data should only be done in the controller (which acts on an action).

Answer (score 1):

If you're generating HTML controls with this helper, then you should probably keep the helper out of your model. All your model should be concerned about is data itself - not how it is formatted or what is done with it.

It would be better organization to inject the model into the helper: this follows the dependency injection pattern and will let you perform unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

i'd have to say "NO" =) it's better to keep it in the controller because if there's a problem on the model, you'll have to manage it from the view..  or what happens if later you want to add some restrictions, for example: only display the select if the user is logged in or display only a few options, etc.

I'd create a method on the model to retrieve the list of elements. Id call that method from the controller to manage the response (not authorized, not found, etc) and select/modify the corresponding view to display the information..

but that's just me =)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Helpers are generally used to "help" you doing things. I think it doesn't really matter too much if you are using them inside the controller or the model or both.